# Merge 2 dataframes using the first column as the index

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

```
df 1:
   Condition   Currency   Total Hours   
0    Used        USD          100
1    Used        USD           75
2    Used        USD           13
3    Used        USD          NaN

df 2:
    Condition   Currency   Total Hours   
1    Used        USD           99
3    New         USD         1000

Desired Result:
   Condition   Currency   Total Hours   
0    Used        USD          100
1    Used        USD           99
2    Used        USD           13
3     New        USD         1000
```

How would I merge the two dataframes using the first column as the index (index) and overwrite the values of df1 with those of df2?

I have tried a variety of variations and nothing seems to work. A few examples I tried:

```
pd.merge(df, df1) = result is an empty dataframe
df.combine_first(df1) = the result is a dataframe but with the same values as df1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `update`:

```
df.update(df2)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  Condition Currency  Total Hours
0      Used      USD        100.0
1      Used      USD         99.0
2      Used      USD         13.0
3       New      USD       1000.0
```

Comment: This doesn't output anything at all.

Comment: @Arty it updates the original `df`. The print out is result of `print(df)`.